# How will node.js support for threads affect node cluster?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

From node.js documentation on [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html):

> A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take advantage of multi-core systems, the user will sometimes want to launch a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.
>
> The cluster module allows easy creation of child processes that all share server ports.

Does the arrival of [Node.js v11.8.0 threading support](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) make clustering redundant?

The docs on worker threads also say this:

> Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. They will not help much with I/O-intensive work. Node.js’s built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be.

I'm a bit confused on this, can somebody please clarify? Is cluster still relevant after multi (worker) thread support?

Comment: Why would it affect node cluster?

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure, cluster appeared to fill a gap because of single threading, with multi-threading is it still relevant?

Comment: of course it is. all they did was enable workers without a flag. it’s been available with a flag for a while now